# What is numpy empty doing under the hood when I allocate a massive ndarray?

Tags: python, c, memory-management, numpy, linux-kernel

I was looking at how much space numpy arrays consume in memory and I noticed a peculiar behavior:

When I ran `x = np.empty((1000000, 7, 64, 64), dtype=np.uint8)`

My computer with 16GB of memory did not crash. Instead it was sailing smoothly with 2GB of memory allocated.

This numpy array should weigh in at 26.70 GB, but something lazy seems to be happening. When I add one, then the laziness stops immediately, and my program hangs and them gets a `MemoryError`.

I'm wondering how numpy does this under the hood.

I took a look at `numpy.core.multiarray`, and found `numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c` with this bit of code that seems to be the definition of empty:

```
static PyObject *
array_empty(PyObject *NPY_UNUSED(ignored), PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{

    static char *kwlist[] = {"shape","dtype","order",NULL};
    PyArray_Descr *typecode = NULL;
    PyArray_Dims shape = {NULL, 0};
    NPY_ORDER order = NPY_CORDER;
    npy_bool is_f_order;
    PyArrayObject *ret = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "O&|O&O&", kwlist,
                PyArray_IntpConverter, &shape,
                PyArray_DescrConverter, &typecode,
                PyArray_OrderConverter, &order)) {
        goto fail;
    }

    switch (order) {
        case NPY_CORDER:
            is_f_order = NPY_FALSE;
            break;
        case NPY_FORTRANORDER:
            is_f_order = NPY_TRUE;
            break;
        default:
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
                            "only 'C' or 'F' order is permitted");
            goto fail;
    }

    ret = (PyArrayObject *)PyArray_Empty(shape.len, shape.ptr,
                                            typecode, is_f_order);

    PyDimMem_FREE(shape.ptr);
    return (PyObject *)ret;

 fail:
    Py_XDECREF(typecode);
    PyDimMem_FREE(shape.ptr);
    return NULL;
}
```

I'm wondering how this laziness is achieved in C, and where else it will pop up in numpy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that the **kernel** may perform lazy allocations. I.e. `malloc` doesn't actually reserve the memory. When the memory is accessed the first time then a page fault will occur and the kernel will perform the actual allocation (and may decide to only allocate that page of memory and not the whole array).

In other words: C isn't being lazy. It's the kernel that is deferring the allocation.

The error happens when you try to add one to the array elements because that operation modifies all memory locations, and thus the kernel is forced to actually fit all the array in memory and fails.

---

I'm not an expert in OS memory management, so the above is what I remember of the OS course. One reference for this can be found [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html#ss9.6). Quoting from it:

> Linux on the other hand is seriously broken. It will by default answer
>   "yes" to most requests for memory, in the hope that programs ask for
>   more than they actually need.

What it's saying is that the kernel `malloc` almost never return a `NULL`, even if the required memory is too big. It "hopes" that the user isn't actually going to use all the memory they request so that he can avoid loading some pages and fit the required data anyway. Obviously this isn't always true.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't go nearly as far as to call the Linux kernel *"seriously broken"* just because it allows for overcommitting virtual memory. If the kernel only allocated virtual memory for which it could strictly guarantee enough physical storage then you'd end up in equally absurd situations where the kernel would refuse to cough up any memory for new objects even though 80% of the RAM is unused, simply because, say, some lazy developer decided to `malloc` a 16GB array where only 1GB was needed.