# Python3: Heap memory not getting released when expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management

I have a class that has a cache implemented as a `dict` for numpy arrays, which can occupy GBs of data.

```
class WorkOperations(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_cache: Dict[str, Dict[str, Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]] = {}

    def get_data(key):
        if key not in data_cache:
            add_data(key)
        return self.data_cache[key]

    def add_data(key)
        result = run_heavy_calculation(key)
        self.data_cache[key] = result
```

I am testing the code with this function  -

```
import gc

def perform_operations()
    work_operations = WorkOperations()

    # input_keys gives a list of keys to process
    for keys in input_keys():
        data = work_operations.get_data(key)
        do_some_operation(data)

    del work_operations

perform_operations()
gc.collect()
```

The result of `run_heavy_calculation` is heavy in memory and soon `data_cache` grows and occupies memory in GBs (which is expected).

But memory does not get released even after `perform_operations()` is done. I tried adding `del work_operations` and invoking `gc.collect()` but that did not help either. I checked memory of the process after several hours, but the memory was still not freed up.

If I don't use caching (`data_cache`) at all (at the cost of latency), memory never goes high.

I am wondering what is it that is taking memory. I tried running `tracemalloc`, but it just showed lines occupying memory in KBs. I also took a memory dump with `gdb` by looking at memory address from process `pmap` and `/proc/<pid>/smaps`, but that is really long and even with hexeditor I couldn't figure out much.

I am measuring memory used by the process using `top` command and looking at `RES`. I also tried outputting memory in the end from within python process as well with -

```
import psutils
import gc
import logging

GIGABYTE = 1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0

perform_operations()
gc.collect()

memory_full_info = psutil.Process().memory_full_info()
logging.info(f"process memory after running the process {memory_full_info.uss / GIGABYTE}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce on Ubuntu  with this :

```py
import itertools
import time
import os
from typing import Dict, Tuple

import numpy as np
import psutil  # installed with pip


process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

SIZE = 10**7


def run_heavy_calculation(key):
    array1 = np.zeros(SIZE)
    array2 = np.zeros(SIZE)
    # Linux use "virtual memory", which means that the memory required for the arrays was allocated, but will not
    # be actually deducted until we use them, so we write some 1 into them
    # cf: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516888/11384184
    for i in range(0, SIZE, 1000):
        array1[i] = 1
        array2[i] = 1
    return {key: (array1, array2)}


class WorkOperations(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_cache: Dict[str, Dict[str, Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]] = {}

    def get_data(self, key):
        if key not in self.data_cache:
            self.add_data(key)
        return self.data_cache[key]

    def add_data(self, key):
        result = run_heavy_calculation(key)
        self.data_cache[key] = result


def perform_operations(input_keys):
    work_operations = WorkOperations()

    for key in input_keys():
        data = work_operations.get_data(key)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(key, process.memory_info().rss / 10**9)

    del work_operations


perform_operations(lambda: map(str, itertools.product("abcdefgh", "0123456789")))  # dummy keys
print("after operations", process.memory_info().rss / 10**9)
input("pause")
```

```
('a', '0') 0.113106944
('a', '1') 0.195014656
('a', '2') 0.276926464
...
('h', '7') 6.421118976
('h', '8') 6.503030784
('h', '9') 6.584942592
after operations 0.031363072
pause
```

It climbed up to using 6,5 Go of RAM, then returned from the function and all of it was released.

You can add a [finalizer (`__del__`)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) to the class `WorkOperations` :

```py
    def __del__(self):
        print("deleted")
```

I see it printed between the last operation's print and the one after.
Although it does not guarantee that this will always be the case ([cf this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40616594/11384184)), it strongly indicates that everything is working as intended : event without the `del`, the functions returns (hence the scope is lost), so the reference count for `work_operations` gets to 0, and then gets GC'ed.

It can be checked with [`sys.getrefcount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount) too :

```py
    print(sys.getrefcount(work_operations) - 1)  # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/510417/11384184
    del work_operations
```

which for me print `1`.

Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and info on your system.